# Какой стиль можно использовать для текста в placeholder вместо margin?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, placeholder

Нужно сместить текст placeholder'a. Так как margin на ::placeholder не действует, может есть что-то похожее?

Comment: `padding`......

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам поможет `padding:`. Вот [ссылка](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, padding?

```css
::placeholder {
  color: blue;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="test">
```

Answer (score 1):

вам поможет свойство text-indent:
например:

```
<input type='password' placeholder='Придумайте пароль' className="userPassword" />
```

```
.userPassword {
text-indent: 10px;
}
```